# Gradle "run" fails -- but java -cp build works

Tags: java, gradle

New to gradle and trying to build a simple Java project. The following works:

```
java -classpath build/libs/Arverne-1.0.jar arverne.ArverneMain
[!] Arverne starting up ...
```

However, attempting to execute the "run" command from gradle fails:

```
gradle run
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:run
Error: Could not find or load main class src.main.java.arverne.ArverneMain
:run FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':run'.
> Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 5.134 secs
```

The directory structure is:

```
.
├── Arverne.iml
├── arverne.properties
├── build
│   ├── classes
│   │   └── main
│   │       └── arverne
│   │           └── ArverneMain.class
│   ├── dependency-cache
│   ├── libs
│   │   └── Arverne-1.0.jar
│   └── tmp
│       └── jar
│           └── MANIFEST.MF
├── build.gradle
├── build.gradle~
├── out
│   └── production
│       └── Arverne
│           └── arverne
│               └── ArverneMain.class
└── src
    └── main
        └── java
            └── arverne
                └── ArverneMain.java

16 directories, 9 files
```

And finally the class implementation is:

```
package arverne;

public class ArverneMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("[!] Arverne starting up ...");
    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please show all relevant parts of the Gradle build script, along with output of `gradle -v`.

Comment: HA -- you nailed it. I had the wrong class name in build.gradle for the mainClassName key.

Comment: Glad you found the problem.